# Current year in RTF Template

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I am using the condition `<?if:contains(ENT_LUPD,'2022')?>` to find if the date is in the year 2022, How to tweak this to get current year instead of 2022, so that next year the tag checks in 2023 ?

Comment: Do you have access to change the XML output/Data Definition?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use get_year function on sysdate to extract year, please check below link : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e22254/extend_func.htm#BIPRD3160
2. If the source is database, you can write query to fetch current year from dual and use that attribute here.